# Is every connected compact manifold homeomorphic to a ball with parts of its surface identified?

Tags: manifolds

Part of what's motivating this question is the idea of putting "coordinates" on a manifold.  The connection is that: given a manifold, if it is homeomorphic to an $n$-ball with parts of its surface identified, then it would be homeomorphic to an $n$-cube with parts of its surface identified.  This allows us to impose a coordinate system on the manifold.

So, if the answer to the question is "no", then it seems that there would be a (connected compact) manifold we cannot put coordinates on.

In 2 dimensions, the answer is "yes", which is clear by looking at the [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Construction_from_polygons) of the manifold.

A more general question would be whether every connected $n$-manifold can be constructed by starting with an open $n$-ball, adding some points on the surface, and identifying some of those surface points.

Comment: Can the manifold have a boundary?

Comment: @mr_e_man Let's stick with manifolds without boundary, though if you have a counterexample, reference, etc. involving a manifold with boundary I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42234/rugged-manifold

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the exponential map, and reading about fundamental polyhedra and Dirichlet domains...